# AJAX: How to clear interval if there is no more result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am wondering how will I clear my ajax's setInterval if there are zero result found.

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imageLoader = {}

    imageLoader.render = function(event){
        $.ajax({
            url: UAI+'/useraccountimages/loadimage',
            type: 'post',
            data: { 
                id : UID,
                },
            success: function(data){
                $("#available_images").html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    imageLoader.interval = setInterval(imageLoader.render,5000);

    imageLoader.render();
});
```

Comment: In your success handler, test `data`. So if "no more result" is signified by an empty string, clear your interval if `(data === '')`.

Comment: Completing halfer's answer : `window.clearInterval(imageLoader.interval)`

Comment: can I clearInterval outside the scope? I mean can I check @var data outside the scope??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure with the code, just follow the "logic" !

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var imageLoader = {}

        imageLoader.render = function(event){
            $.ajax({
                url: UAI+'/useraccountimages/loadimage',
                type: 'post',
                data: { 
                    id : UID,
                },
                success: function(data){
                    if (data.is(':empty')) {
                        clearInterval(imageLoader.interval);
                    }
                    $("#available_images").html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        imageLoader.interval = setInterval(imageLoader.render,5000);

        imageLoader.render();
});
```

With the function "clearInterval" to stop it. ([stopInterval description](http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=830))